# Javascript - using $(this) in a function inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, settimeout

Basically, there is a screen and if you link a button, the screen slides up and then another screen appears. The problem is, the slideUp() function takes some time to execute and the other screen appears before the slideUp function is even done executing. I want it so that the other screen waits until the slideUp function is done executing until the other screen shows up. Here is the main Javascript:

```
$('#sidebar ul li a').click(function(){ 

    $('#sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('clicked'); // when an <a> is clicked, remove .clicked class from any other <a>'s

    $(this).addClass('clicked');

    hidePrevSlide(); //this calls slideUp in the current screen
    $(this).showCurrentSlide(); //this shows another screen before hidePrevSlide is even finished executing / sliding Up
});
```

I tried

```
hidePrevSlide(function(){
    $(this).showCurrentSlide();
});
```

but then this breaks the code for some reason. Is there any way to accomplish what I am doing?

Comment: Sure I'll try, give me like 5 minutes

Comment: @stevenmarvell Edit: Okay is it possible to just let me know if there is a way to use $(this) in a function inside a function? Or a way to wait 3 seconds before executing the $(this).showCUrrentSlide(); line? I tried using setTimeout but it didn't work.. jsfiddle'ing it would take quite a bit of time since I am using django and the html is mixed with a bunch of python code and variables.

Comment: you almost certainly want to do a `that = this` type thing and then pass `that` into the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#sidebar ul li a').click(function(){ 

    $('#sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('clicked'); // when an <a> is clicked, remove .clicked class from any other <a>'s

    $(this).addClass('clicked');

    var current_slide=$(this);
    hidePrevSlide(function(){
        current_slide.showCurrentSlide();
    });
    $(this).showCurrentSlide(); //this shows another screen before hidePrevSlide is even finished executing / sliding Up
});
```

I can see that you are running into a scoping issue. By storing `$(this)` before the function, you will be able to access that variable inside the function below.

For a small optimization, you should avoid using multiple `$(this)` so we can re-use our `current_slide` variable like so:

```
$('#sidebar ul li a').click(function(){ 
    var current_slide=$(this);

    $('#sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('clicked'); // when an <a> is clicked, remove .clicked class from any other <a>'s

    current_slide.addClass('clicked');

    hidePrevSlide(function(){
        current_slide.showCurrentSlide();
    });
    current_slide.showCurrentSlide(); //this shows another screen before hidePrevSlide is even finished executing / sliding Up
});
```

Comment: Hm, I used your code but it is still giving the same problem. I'm going to try using setTimeout using current_slide and see if that works.

Comment: Perfect, okay so the solution was in fact to store $(this) in a variable before the function. I don't know why     hidePrevSlide(function(){
        current_slide.showCurrentSlide();
    });
didn't work but I did store current_slide in a variable and then did
 window.setTimeout(function() {
     current_slide.showCurrentSlide();
 }, 500);
and it worked.. thanks! Also, how do I write code inside a comment when I am making a comment on stackoverflow?